# Move a window Manager?

Tags: android

I have a WindowManager set up like this.

```
myWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
 myWindowManager.addView(view, params);
```

I add a View object to a WindowManager like this. I want to move this WindowManager to the TOP Center. I am not sure how I can do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Gravity` for you view. i.e.

```
myWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    //edited
    params.gravity=Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTA;

    myWindowManager.addView(view, params);
```

You can also check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html) for more details.

Comment: I tried that. It just places my windowmanager in the middle of the screen but not sure how to move it to the top of the screen.

Comment: set that `params.gravity=Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTA`. i think it should work.